# An error regarding reading a character from Scanner and convert it to a Unicode

Tags: java, unicode, character, variable-assignment, symbols

I have a code to convert a symbol into its Unicode. I have attached my code below.

The problem is that I have the correct output if I use the code without the `for` loop to ask for entering several symbols. While using for loop after asking to enter a symbol, I receive an error. I tried to find the problem, but had no success. Maybe it is easy to find it out but for now I am not able to find it.

Any help to fix the error is appreciated. Thanks.

[This is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/givM8.jpg)

Below, I put the code as text in case you want to test it:

```
package practicejava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnicodeSymbol 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char symbol;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // To read a first char or symbol by scanner
        myScanner.useDelimiter("");

        // Ask for the number of input
        System.out.println("How many symbols do you want to try?\t");
        // To validate positive integer input from scanner
        int input;
        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
            while (!myScanner.hasNextInt()) 
            {
                System.out.println("That's not a positive number!");
                myScanner.next();
            }
            // if the condition is false:
            input = myScanner.nextInt();
        } 
        while (input <= 0);
        System.out.println("Thank you! Your input is: " + input);

        // To convert and print each registered symbol to unicode
        for (int i=0; i <= input; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a symbol or character:\t");
            symbol = myScanner.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
            int code = (int) symbol;
            System.out.println("This is the unicode for symbol " + symbol + " :\t" + code);   
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

[This is the stack-trace image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUAxh.jpg)

Comment: The first thing you should provide when you have an error is a stacktrace

Comment: Right, I did. I know the error line which is about reading from scanner. But while not using "for loop" or "while" that line is ok. 

I know the problem is using the Scanner in while loop but i don't know how to fix it. I declared another scanner after while loop to fix the problem but it didn't work.

Error line:    symbol = myScanner.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

Comment: Your question still doesn't have a stack trace.

Comment: You mean i should put the stacktrace report here? It is my first experience asking a question, I do not know what to do exactly. sorry.

Comment: I added a link to the stack trace.